# How to pass date from controller to modal in ionic 1

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

i want to pass data from controller to ionic modal , but i didn't find any method to do that. so please suggest something

```
what i have tried:-

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'confirm_booking.html',
  controller: 'confirm_bookCtl',
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});

but $modal is undefined in controller
```

Answer (score 0):

//First you don't need to declare a controller because you call your modal from your controller

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
   $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal-template.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up',
   }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
   });

   $scope.openModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.show();
   };

   $scope.closeModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.hide();
   };

   //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
   $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      $scope.modal.remove();
   });

   // Execute action on hide modal
   $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
      // Execute action
   });

   // Execute action on remove modal
   $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
      // Execute action
   });
});
```

Maybe better you visit this page

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/ionic_js_modal.htm